# How can I fix if/else statement in javascript function to run all functions on the first click and only one function every click after using a value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this application where I click the button and nested divs appear with an image in the inner most div. the textarea keeps track of how many times the button is clicked and with every click the nested divs remain but the image swaps between the initial image and a second image.

I only need the nested divs to appear on the first click and have only the image change with every click after that, using the value in the textbox to make that happen like i did with the addbutterfly function.

in that function i took the value from the textarea and made it so if the value is even the 1 image shows and if it is not the other will show.

i am not sure how to make that work for the function applied to the button so that if value is equal to 0 the divs and the intial image are created and if it is not equal to 0 then just the addbutterfly function is ran which would swap the images back and forth.

i attempted with the most basic way i could think of. which was to pull the value from the textarea the same way i did with the addbutterfly function and make it so if value == 0 do all the functions, else only do the addbutterfly function but it isnt working.

before i added that if/else statement the app ran fine but would add all the divs with every click.
this is my error:
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 102,
"colno": 45

```js
var i = 0;

function runTogether1() {
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
  if (value == 0) {
    addDiv();
    addDiv2();
    addDiv3();
    addbutterfly();
    incrementValue();
  } else {
    addbutterfly();
  }
}

function addDiv() {
  var div1 = document.createElement('div');
  div1.classList.add('div1');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
}

function addDiv2() {
  var div2 = document.createElement('div');
  div2.classList.add('div2');
  document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[i].appendChild(div2);
}

function addDiv3() {
  var div3 = document.createElement('div');
  div3.classList.add('div3');
  document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[i].appendChild(div3);
}

function addbutterfly() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  // Get the value of the "textfield"
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);

  // If the value is even, add "bfly2.gif", otherwhise add "bfly1.gif"
  img.src = value % 2 === 0 ? "bfly2.gif" : "bfly1.gif";
  document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i].appendChild(img);
  i++;
}


function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('id1').value = value;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="bflyjs.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button">
    <button onclick="runTogether1()"> 
          click to get nested divs
      </button>
    <textarea id="id1"> 
      </textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The textarea doesn't contain `0` at the beginning. `parseInt()` is returning `NaN`.

Comment: so can i make it be that if it returns NaN only run the first part and if it has a value run the other part? i tried putting the 0 in the textarea like the solution below but that only works the first time and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a value to the `textarea` in order to read the value by ID.

```js
var i = 0;

function runTogether1() {
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
  if (value == 0) {
    addDiv();
    addDiv2();
    addDiv3();
    addbutterfly();
    incrementValue();
  } else {
    addbutterfly();
  }
}

function addDiv() {
  var div1 = document.createElement('div');
  div1.classList.add('div1');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
}

function addDiv2() {
  var div2 = document.createElement('div');
  div2.classList.add('div2');
  document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[i].appendChild(div2);
}

function addDiv3() {
  var div3 = document.createElement('div');
  div3.classList.add('div3');
  document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[i].appendChild(div3);
}

function addbutterfly() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  // Get the value of the "textfield"
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);

  // If the value is even, add "bfly2.gif", otherwhise add "bfly1.gif"
  img.src = value % 2 === 0 ? "bfly2.gif" : "bfly1.gif";
  document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i].appendChild(img);
  i++;
}


function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('id1').value = value;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="bflyjs.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button">
    <button onclick="runTogether1()"> 
              click to get nested divs
          </button>
    <textarea id="id1"> 0
          </textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is `document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i]` supposed to be? You only add one `div3` element, so this fails after you increment `i`.

Comment: thanks but this does not work for me because now the function works when 0 is there and thats it. the images dont swap and the count doesnt update in the textarea. in a worst place than when i started

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10)` is returning `NaN` because the textarea is empty when the script starts. So use `isNaN()` rather than comparing to `0`, just like you do in `incrementValue()`.

```js
var i = 0;

function runTogether1() {
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    addDiv();
    addDiv2();
    addDiv3();
    addbutterfly();
    incrementValue();
  } else {
    addbutterfly();
  }
}

function addDiv() {
  var div1 = document.createElement('div');
  div1.classList.add('div1');
  document.body.appendChild(div1);
}

function addDiv2() {
  var div2 = document.createElement('div');
  div2.classList.add('div2');
  document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[i].appendChild(div2);
}

function addDiv3() {
  var div3 = document.createElement('div');
  div3.classList.add('div3');
  document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[i].appendChild(div3);
}

function addbutterfly() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  // Get the value of the "textfield"
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);

  // If the value is even, add "bfly2.gif", otherwhise add "bfly1.gif"
  img.src = value % 2 === 0 ? "bfly2.gif" : "bfly1.gif";
  document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i].appendChild(img);
  i++;
}


function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('id1').value = value;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="bflyjs.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button">
    <button onclick="runTogether1()"> 
          click to get nested divs
      </button>
    <textarea id="id1"> 
      </textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks this i still get an error for the clicks after the first one. the image never updates nor the counter. the error is now in the addbutterfly function and reads: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined. this was a function that previously worked to swap the images and didnt mess with the counter.

Comment: See my comment above about `document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i]`. That doesn't work when `i` is not `0`. You only call `addDiv3()` the first time, so there's only one of that DIV. Why are you indexing it with `i`?

Comment: i see your other comment and guess that where the issue lies. idk how to go back and fix these things to mesh and work together. i just need the divs created once, to have the image swap with every click and the textarea to keep a count.

Comment: Use `[0]` to get the DIV, not `[i]`.

Comment: Idk how I arrived at that last night but it did work to swap the images but it would recreated all of the nested divs with the different image one after the other and the textarea value would still update. if it was even the nested divs would be created and the even image would be in it, vice versa for if the value was odd.

Comment: when i put 0 instead of i it just adds images over and over to the same nested dov. does not replace it and the counter does not update

Comment: `appendChild()` appends, it doesn't replace.

Comment: If you want to replace, you should remove the old image before adding the new one.

Comment: All these other problems are unrelated to the question, which is about how to run different code the first time.

Comment: thanks for your help forreal. I have it now where the divs are only created once, the counter updates, and images getting added are alternating for even/odd clicks. but yea they arent replacing. Ill work on that and see if i cant figure it out